# My custom built minimal kernel linux won't boot with the error "Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(8,1)

Tags: linux, kernel, kernel-panic, vfs

Sorry about the noob question. I just built the cross compiler, created the filesystem hierarchy, compiled the kernel and BusyBox and put it on a USB and installed GRUB. When I boot it, I get this:

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(8,1)
```

I would say that I tried to fix it, but I don't even know what the error means, so I don't know how to begin. I searched google and all I found were distro-specific answers. My inittab (not sure if it matters):

```
::sysinit:/etc/rc.d/startup

tty1::respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty1
tty2::respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty2
tty3::respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty3
tty4::respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty4
tty5::respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty5
tty6::respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty6

::shutdown:/etc/rc.d/shutdown
::ctrlaltdel:/sbin/reboot
```

My fstab:

```
# file system  mount-point  type   options          dump  fsck
#                                                         order

rootfs          /               auto    defaults        1      1
proc            /proc           proc    defaults        0      0
sysfs           /sys            sysfs   defaults        0      0
devpts          /dev/pts        devpts  gid=4,mode=620  0      0
tmpfs           /dev/shm        tmpfs   defaults        0      0
```

Thank you!
**Edit: I now get another error after troubleshooting: Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found. EDIT 2: Now I get the error “Kernel panic - not syncing: Requested init /sbin/init failed (error -2).”**

Comment: Sadly not, I took a look at that earlier and I didn’t find a solution that worked for me.

Comment: You likely didn't include the drivers necessary to access the disk.  If so, can you boot a live distro, edit your question, and include the output of `lspci -k`?

Comment: Alright. If it matters at all (which i’m sure it doesn’t) I think I may have included the file system drivers as a module

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't make your root filesystem driver a module unless you want to deal with an initrd.

Comment: If I can avoid rebuilding the kernel, how would I go about making an initrd?

Comment: There are a lot of resources online on how to build an initrd.  I never do -- I just build the things I need to boot into the kernel.

Comment: I’ll probably just recompile the kernel I guess. Thank you for the response!

Comment: So apparently my filesystem drivers were not modules... I'm completely lost now

Comment: The error message means the kernel is expecting to find a root file system on the block device with major device number 8, and minor number 1. This normally means partition 1 on the first SATA disk (/dev/sda1). Where is your root file system, i.e. on what kind of device? Do you have drivers compiled into the kernel for SATA disks, or whatever kind of device your root file system is on? Is it recognized by the kernel at boot? Do you see anything in the messages displayed at boot? You can use the root= kernel command line parameter to change the root device.

Comment: I have probably almost every disk driver, and I made sure they aren't modules. I am running it off a USB stick.

Comment: I had my root set as /dev/sda1 and that seemed to do it. I'm not using an initrd, do I still need a root filesystem? All I see in the messages is the kernel panic and then the stack trace.

Comment: @JohanMyréen I get another error now, I edited my question with it

Comment: You will have to arrange so that the kernel can find an  init program (e.g. Busybox's init) at the path `/sbin/init` on your root filesystem. Alternatively, you can use the `init=` kernel command line parameter to specify an alternate file name.

Comment: @JohanMyréen I tried that and got the same (error -2). I confirmed it exists.

Comment: What kind of file is `/sbin/init`? A binary, or a shell script? If it is a shell script, do you have a shell (`/bin/sh`) on the root filesystem? If it is a binary file, is it statically or dynamically linked? See also https://busybox.net/FAQ.html#init

Comment: @JohanMyréen It is a statically linked binary.